# how to restrict access for a particular user or login in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I restrict access for CREATE, ALTER, DROP statements to a particular user/login in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Read about the [`GRANT` statement on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965.aspx)

Comment: This is a better place to look [http://dba.stackexchange.com/](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) [These posts should relate to your question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=How+do+I+restrict+access+for+CREATE%2C+ALTER%2C+DROP+statements+to+a+particular+user%2Flogin+in+%5BSQL-Server%5D&submit=search)

Answer (score 0):

The SQL permission hierarchy starts with Logins at the Instance level and then Users at the database level, which map to a login at the instance.

A user and it's associated login will not have any permissions until you explicitly grant them through Server roles and database role (these are collections of principles and secuables that simplify permission management) or by granting permissions directly on an object.

In SQL Server, DENY overrides GRANT so if your user is already in a role that grants them the permission to issue DDL against the object in question, then you can deny them permissions to the specific object in question. An example of the syntax for this, based on denying alter permissions to a table is as follows:

```
DENY ALTER ON OBJECT::dbo.MyTable TO MyUser
```

Although you can of course to this through the GUI as well. In SSMS, drill through Databases>MyDatabase>Security>Users then open the properties of the user in question and change their assignments here.

Security in the database world is incredibly important and I would strongly suggest that you investigate the use of Windows Groups Server Roles and Database Roles to manage your permissions rather than setting permissions in an ad-hoc fashion. I would also recommend a fully documented security policy and exception document which detail the precise security structure in your organisation. Keeping these working documents will allow you to keep track easily of who can do what. This aids in avoiding non-repudability issues and makes auditing easy.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trigger , if u want  for only 1 database  use the commented code @event data and write your logic

```
 CREATE TRIGGER [permissions]
    ON ALL SERVER
    FOR CREATE_Table,DROP_Table,ALTER_Table,
        CREATE_View,ALTER_View,Drop_View,
        CREATE_Trigger,ALTER_Trigger,Drop_Trigger,
        CREATE_DATABASE,DROP_DATABASE,ALTER_DATABASE,
        CREATE_USER,DROP_USER,ALTER_USER,
        CREATE_FUNCTION,ALTER_FUNCTION,DROP_FUNCTION,
        CREATE_Procedure,ALTER_Procedure,DROP_Procedure,
        CREATE_ASSEMBLY,ALTER_ASSEMBLY,DROP_ASSEMBLY,
        CREATE_ROLE,ALTER_ROLE,DROP_ROLE

AS

BEGIN   



 --   DECLARE @Eventdata XML,@ActionType varchar(100),@DataBase varchar(100)
    --SET @Eventdata = EVENTDATA()
        --SET @ActionType=@Eventdata.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]',    'nvarchar(100)')
 --   SET @DataBase=@Eventdata.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')

   IF  SYSTEM_USER  IN ('user')
                BEGIN 
                RAISERROR ('not allowed.', 16, 1 );
                ROLLBACK;   
    END




  END
```